# Errors while running anaconda

Tags: linux, anaconda3, ubuntu-22.04

I faced to some problems while running anaconda navigator on ubuntu 22.04.
When I run the navigator via terminal, some errors appear. Here they are:

$ ./navigator.sh

qt.svg: link path0_fill hasn't been detected!

qt.svg: link path1_fill hasn't been detected!

qt.svg: link path2_fill hasn't been detected!

qt.svg: link path3_fill hasn't been detected!

qt.svg: link path4_fill hasn't been detected!

qt.svg: link path5_fill hasn't been detected!

qt.svg: link path6_fill hasn't been detected!

qt.svg: link path7_fill hasn't been detected!

qt.svg: link path8_fill hasn't been detected!

qt.svg: link path9_fill hasn't been detected!

qt.svg: link path10_fill hasn't been detected!

qt.svg: link path11_fill hasn't been detected!

However navigator runs successfully. I don't know what to do with this.

Comment: If it runs successfully, then I don't see the problem. Those messages may not even be errors.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Problem when i made some changes on Spyder (update). Uninstall and reinstall Spyder or any other IDE that you have updated. It worked for me.

Comment: what is the correct fix if you get this error.. but also want to use spyder?

Comment: uninstall spyder and reinstall it again via anaconda navigator.

Answer (score 0):

The problem goes away if you reinstall `svg.qt` on the command line with:

```
conda install -c benensta qt5
```

[See qt5 info](https://anaconda.org/benensta/qt5).